# Convert Associative array to different array structure

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array, which has some extra character in the value "/".

```
Array
(
    [ID1] => 362/2
    [ID2] => 589/3
    [ID3] => 697/4
    [ID4] => 111/5
    [ID5] => 422/6
)
```

what I want to achieve and get is as follows

```
Array
(
    [ID1] => 362
    [ID1] => 2
    [ID2] => 589
    [ID2] => 3
    [ID3] => 697
    [ID3] => 4
    [ID4] => 111
    [ID4] => 5
    [ID5] => 422
    [ID5] => 6
)
```

And, I have tried to write script in php to solve the above issues...

```
        $exp = array();
        foreach ($value as $val) {
            $pl = explode('/', $val);
            $exp[] = $pl[0] ."=>".$pl[1];
        }

         print_arr($exp);
```

But, I got the following result, In which it is wrong...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 362=>2
    [1] => 589=>3
    [2] => 697=>4
    [3] => 111=>5
    [4] => 422=>6
)
```

how do I do it? some help please?

Comment: What you want to achieve is not possible because keys must be unique. With that restriction in mind, perhaps some other alternative would suit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to have multiple values with the same key.

Probably the best solution for you should be:

```
$exp = array();
foreach ($value as $id => $val) {
  list($first, $second) = explode('/', $val);
  $exp[$id] = array(
    'first'  => $first,
    'second' => $second
  );
}
```

So in the output you will have:

```
array(
  'id1' => array(
    'first'  => 362,
    'second' => 2
  ),
  ...
)
```

Comment: That is perfect answer for me, thanks for your cooperation, I accept is as answer.

Comment: but one more question, if I need to search 2 in this array, how do I do that?

Comment: What for do you want to search ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$exp = array();
$i=1;
    foreach ($value as $val) {
        $pl = explode('/', $val);
        $exp['id'.$i][] = $pl[0];
        $exp['id'.$i][] = $pl[1]; 
        $i++;
    }
```

Your expected array has duplicate Keys which is not possible